# Chaining array assignment in Java

Tags: java

Consider the following code snippet in Java. I know that the statement `temp[index] = index = 0;` in the following code snippet is pretty much unacceptable but it may be necessary for some situations:

```
package arraypkg;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        int[]temp=new int[]{4,3,2,1};
        int index = 1;

        temp[index] = index = 0;
        System.out.println("temp[0] = "+temp[0]);
        System.out.println("temp[1] = "+temp[1]);
    }
}
```

---

It displays the following output on the console.

```
temp[0] = 4
temp[1] = 0
```

---

I do not understand `temp[index] = index = 0;`.

How does `temp[1]` contain `0`? How does this assignment occur?

Comment: What do you expect `temp[1]` to be?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that he expects `index` to first become `0` making `temp[index]` equivalent to `temp[0]` so that only the first element is modified.

Comment: The take home message here should be, don't write code this way. Knowing the fiddly bits of Java is a respectable skill, but mostly useless. Code like this simply shouldn't exist, and where it is found should be eradicated immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assignment is done (`temp[index] = (index = 0)`), right associative.

But first the expression `temp[index]` is evaluated for the LHS variable. At that time `index` is still 1. Then the RHS (`index = 0`) is done.

Comment: +1 - First person to directly address the question the OP is actually asking (about LHS vs. RHS order of evaluation).

Comment: Supporting evidence: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.1

Answer (score 1):

Your statement assigned zero to it.  The statement temp[index] = index = 0 wrote zero into index AND into temp[index].  That's what that meant.  Make all variables to the left of an assignment operator 0.

Answer (score 1):

What that line does is say that `temp[index]` should equal `index` after `index` is assigned the value `0`.

This is why this syntax is mostly unacceptable. It's hard to read and most people don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

you assigned both temp[1] and index to '0'
it running left to right.
think ass temp[index/*  */]